# how to fix the problem regarding crashing of session in google colab after using available RAM even after using small dataset

Tags: crash, ram, using, google-colaboratory, availability

My session in google colab is continously crashing showing "Your session is crashed after using available RAM" even after using small dataset.
test size = 99989*2
train size = 299989*2

I am searching for the solution to this problem but unable to find one.

```
corpus = []
for i in range(0, 299989):
    SentimentText = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]', ' ', dataset1['SentimentText'][i])
    SentimentText = re.sub('<[^<]+?>', ' ', dataset1['SentimentText'][i])
    tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')
    SentimentText = tokenizer.tokenize(SentimentText)
    SentimentText = ' '.join(SentimentText)
    corpus.append(SentimentText)

X_train = cv.fit_transform(corpus)
from sklearn.feature_extraction import text
X_train = text.TfidfTransformer().fit_transform(X_train)

X_train = X_train.toarray()
y_train = dataset.iloc[:, 1].values
```

after executing the third part the error is displayed of session crashing..

Answer (score 0):

Try turning on the GPU from the edit menu and select notebook settings. In the hardware accelerators select GPU. This will increase the size of the RAM.